# Flatness and completions

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness

Suppose $A,B$ are local rings and $f:A\to B$ is a local ring homomorphism. Let $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ be the completions of $A,B$ at their maximal ideals and $\hat{f}$ be the induced map between completions. Is it true that the flatness of $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are equivalent?

I would expect this to be true based on some sort of way to write the functors $B\otimes_A$ and $\hat{B}\otimes_{\hat{A}}$ as compositions of each other and the extension of scalars $\hat{A}\otimes_A$, but I can't figure out how to go from $\hat{f}$ back to $f$.

Comment: You can go from the flatness of $\hat{f}$ back to the flatness of $f$ if $A$ and $B$ are noetherian. In this case, consider $$A \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} B \xrightarrow{\text{faithfully flat}} \hat{B}.$$ The composition is flat since it factors as $$A \xrightarrow{\text{faithfully flat}} \hat{A} \overset{\hat{f}}{\longrightarrow} \hat{B}$$ and the composition of flat maps is flat. Now \[Stacks, [Tag 039V](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/039V)\] implies $f\colon A \to B$ is flat.